# How do I obtain the value for the Fermi Coupling Constant?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, electroweak

I have been given an equation, without an explanation on the constant included.

The equation is the following: $$\Gamma= \frac{7\pi}{24} G^2_{\text{Fermi}}$$

When looking for a value for the Fermi Coupling Constant, $G_{\text{Fermi}}$ , I only seem to find values for $G_{\text{Fermi}}/{(\hbar c)^3}$.

**To obtain the value for  $G_{\text{Fermi}}$,must I just multiply the value I have for $G_{\text{Fermi}}/{(\hbar c)^3}$ by $(\hbar c)^3$ (the product of plancks constant with the speed of light)?**

If so, why is the value of the constant shown in this form , divided by another constant, instead of just being presented as itself?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_interaction#Fermi_constant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most particle theory texts use "natural units" units are such that $\hbar c$ is numerically unity, although it has dimensions $ML^2T^{-2}$ of energy.  $G_0= G_F/(\hbar c)^3$ is usually quoted  units of $GeV^{-2}$. This tells us that $G_F$ itself has units of $GeV$.

You do not tell us what $\Gamma$ is. Is it a decay width? If so, it has dimensions of energy and you probably need $G_F$, and not $G_F^2$ or  $G_0$. Anyway knowing the dimensions of $\Gamma$ will tell you.

Comment: He might be thinking of a weak decay width, in which case his expression is dimensionally oxymoronic.... If it were muon decay, he'd need five powers of its mass to boot...

Answer (score 0):

As described above, particle physics usually introduces units of $c=\hbar = 1$. This in turn means, that obtaining any useful results in units you may know, requires multiplying the result (or in your case the constants involved) by a factor of the form $\hbar^a \cdot c^b$ where $a,b$ are always uniquely determined. So in your case, you would need to multiply by $(\hbar c)^3 = (200MeVfm)^3$ to obtain the result in "normal units". However, it is often advisable to stay in natural units until the very end of your calculation (often less prone to errors), since the unique way of converting assures the correct solution.